# Hair particles in Cycles Render jumping to mesh origin when mesh is animated

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hair

I have a character with particle system hair. When I animate him, hair particles randomly jump to the mesh object origin in certain frames.

[image: Frame with error]

The character's hair modifier used to be on his body mesh, which has a subdivision surface modifier. But in this version, I created a separate scalp mesh which has no subdivision surface modifier. I've regenerated the hair in particle edit mode, but the problem still persists. So I'm at a loss. I'm on Blender version 2.78c, using the Cycles render engine.

Here's a link to the blender file containing the scalp and particle system, the cache (which is still syncing at the time of posting), and some example render frames:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/s9m0ydegue6j0sp/AACMZZg6syIXe-xlaA5akPTIa?dl=0

Thank's for any help you can provide.

-Jonathan